# How do i connect all the dots on my circle so that it makes a pattern?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So I was trying to make a circle with a certain amount of dots on it with all the dots connected with each other. So if there are 10 dots, dot 1 would be connected with all the other ones and so is dot 2. Eventually it makes a pretty pattern. I already have a code for putting the dots on the circle, and I already succeeded in making the bottom dot connect with the rest, but I cannot think of a way to make the rest of the dots connect as well. This is my code:

```
import turtle

tur = turtle.Turtle()
bob = turtle.Turtle()
screen = turtle.Screen()

screen.setup(800,800)

stippen = int(screen.numinput("How many?" , "How many dots do you want to draw? " , minval = 1 , maxval = 25)) #the user can input a number of dots between 1 and 25

formula = 360/stippen #this makes sure the dots are at an equal distance from the other ones

r = 300 #radius of my circle

def roos():
    tur.ht()
    bob.ht()
    bob.speed(0)
    tur.speed(0)
    bob.up()
    tur.up()
    tur.goto(0,-300) #this is always the bottom dot
    bob.goto(0,-300)
    
    for i in range(stippen): #this draws the circle with the dots 
        tur.down()
        bob.down()
        tur.circle(r,formula,150) #it draws a piece of the circle
        tur.dot() #then draws a dot and this is done until the circle is full
        bob.goto(tur.pos()) #bob goes to the dot tur is at and draws a line
        bob.up()
        bob.goto(0,-300) #then bob goes back down to go to the other dots tur draws
        tur.up()

roos()

turtle.done()
```

So I made the bottom dot connect with the rest of the dots, but how do I make it so that the rest is connected as well? I tried getting the coordinates of all the dots drawn, but I couldn't figure it out and I also thought there would be an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a nested loop.  Give this a try:

```
    for _ in range(stippen):    
        for _ in range(stippen):
            tur.down()
            bob.down()
            tur.circle(r,formula,150)
            tur.dot()
            bob_pos = bob.pos()  # remember where bob started
            bob.goto(tur.pos())
            bob.up()
            bob.goto(bob_pos)  # send bob back
            tur.up()
        bob.circle(r, formula, 150)  # send bob around the circle and repeat
```